# How to create a single line model (SLM), multi line model (MLM) and/or IBIS model of an interconnect for simulation?

Tags: simulation, high-speed, ibis

I want to create a single line model, multi line model and/or IBIS model of an interconnect for simulation in Hyperlynx software but can't understand how to do it when the manufacturer has given no related parameters whatsoever. The interconnect is this one:

[TST shrouded connector (Samtec)](http://www.samtec.com/technical-specifications/Default.aspx?SeriesMaster=TST)

Comment: They have some HyperLynx models for connectors more geared/intended for high speed, e.g [TFM](https://wwws.samtec.com/technical-specifications/Default.aspx?SeriesMaster=TFM&DisplayOption=Electrical). For TST it looks like you'll have email sig@samtec.com or fill out their [on-line form](https://wwws.samtec.com/technical-specifications/SpiceIBISRequest.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

It's a connector: -

[image]

And therefore a very basic component. You should be able to easily estimate inter-pin capacitance from dimensions. Ditto pin inductances and depending on the plating material you should be able to calculate resistances.

But, it's only worth doing if you are sending signals through the pins greater than about 50 MHz.

Alternatively ask Samtec - they are normally fairly amenable to questions like this. [This](https://wwws.samtec.com/technical-specifications/Default.aspx?SeriesMaster=TST) document looks like it contains some information that will be useful.

Comment: Can you pass me some link to documentation which has formulas and methodologies to calculate inter-pin cap, induct .etc. based on plating and dimensions? Is there a book or published paper on it?